# Excel Macro: Replace formulas and save sheet as own file without changing original document

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a lot of worksheets. I only work on sheets marked with a `!`. I want to replace all formulas by values and store the sheets as own .xls files. My script is exactly doing that. My problem is that the original document is affected as well. Is there a way to replace the values only on the copied sheet which will be stored so the original document stays the same?

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Object
Dim xPath As String
Dim isReadable As Boolean
Dim sName As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In wbk.Sheets
    isReadable = (InStr(ws.Name, "!")) > 0

    If isReadable Then
        Debug.Print ws.Name

        Set rng = ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)
        If Not (rng Is Nothing) Then
            For Each cl In rng
                cl.Value = cl.Value
            Next cl
        End If

        sName = Replace(ws.Name, "!", "")
        sName = LCase(Replace(sName, "+", ""))

        ws.Copy

        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & sName & ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        Debug.Print sName
    End If

Next ws
Application.Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done, do not save the changes!"
```

Comment: Do the `SaveAs` before the operations and the original workbook stays intact.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie That is the opposite of what I want to have. ;) The formulas of the original document are replaced but the saved copy has still the formulas.

Comment: If you are saving the copy, then it should be done as @RobinMackenzie states. You are saving the workbook AFTER you change the cells values.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the sheet and work on that:

```
Sub DoStuff()

Dim wsOrig As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim wbOrig As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook

Set wsOrig = ActiveSheet ' or whatever
Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook ' or whatever

For s = 1 To wbOrig.Sheets.Count

    If wbOrig.Sheets(s) ' meets my conditions then....

        Application.SetWarnings False ' don't question if we want to delete thinsg

        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        wsOrig.Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(1)

        wbNew.Sheets(1).Delete ' delete the default Sheet1 of the new workbook
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)

        With wsNew

            ' do all the stuff I want to do

        End With

        wbNew.SaveAs ' whatever

        Application.SetWarnings True

    End If

Next s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to make the changes only on the copied sheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*!*" Then
        ws.Copy
        Set ws2 = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Sheets(1) ' newest workbook
        ws2.Name = LCase(Replace(Replace(ws.Name, "!", ""), "+", ""))
        ws2.UsedRange.Value = ws2.UsedRange.Value
        ws2.Parent.SaveAs ws.Parent.Path & "\" & sName & ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False ' add checks if the file already exist and if path contains illegal characters that are not allowed
        ws2.Parent.Close False
    End If
Next
```